# How to check whether any of the array values are present in a string and also the matching array value using grep in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to check if any of the array values in @val is matching to the string $str. If so I need to get which array value is matched there.

This is for windows running Perl

```
$str ="This is a testabc code ";
@val=("not","hope","test","beta");

#How to find whether any of the @val elements are present in $str and also which element is matching using grep .
```

I need to get the output as "test" is found

Comment: Smartmatch will do it ~~ :-) ... Sorry I was trying to be funny. Smartmatch will do it, but the Perl guys are trying to remove and certainly not encourage its use. Just use a map.

Comment: `grep` and `any` (from List::Util and List::MoreUtils) would be better than `map`

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it:

```
my $str="This is a test code ";
#$str.="not";
my @val=("not","hope","test","beta");
my @m=grep $str=~/$_/, @val;
print "Matched: @m";
print "First match, if any: $m[0]";
```

You should also think about if you want case-insensitive matching. Should "Internet" also match "internet"? And if you want to match whole words only or also parts of words. Should "smart" also match "smartphone"? Change `/$_/` into `/$_/i` to match case-insensitive and into `/\b$_\b/i` to also match whole words only.

Comment: what if $str ="This is a testabc code "; and it matches with test. So how to get that test

Comment: It will match "test" as it is not matching whole words.

To match whole words only use:
my @m=grep $str=~/\b$_\b/, @val;